# Logger Entity in App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

Is it viable to have a logger entity in app engine for writing logs? I'll have an app with ~1500req/sec and am thinking about doing it with a taskqueue. Whenever I receive a request, I would create a task and put it in a queue to write something to a log entity (with a date and string properties).

I need this because I have to put statistics in the site that I think that doing it this way and reading the logs with a backend later would solve the problem. Would rock if I had programmatic access to the app engine logs (from logging), but since that's unavailable, I dont see any other way to do it..

Feedback is much welcome

Comment: Eventually, what do you want to do? The question is not very clear. And regarding writing, do you plan to write 1,500 records per second?

Comment: yup, I do plan to have 1500 requests per second, sometimes. Not in that exact second, but I have to write a new entity for each request. For that I'll spread this work between multiple queues that will write it later. With this, I want to be able to log events related to the request and then use a backend to generate statistics from them.

Comment: I wouldn't have to do this if I was able to programmatically access the logs from the logging module (that are available in the admin console)

Comment: What do you want to do with the records once they're written?

Comment: @Nick, The system as a set of rules that depending on the request, will response with some object. I want to keep statistics on how ofter an object was served. To keep a very low latency needed on the requests, I obviously cannot update anything in the datastore, so I asynchronous write a log entity and process them afterwards.

Comment: @tiagoboldt Can you simply update stats in memcache instead? How important is it that the stats be 100% accurate?

Comment: @nick, it is important.. Billing will later be based on it. I could write to memcache or sharded memcache even and frequently update the stats but data might be lost and I can't accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Accumulate logs and write them in a single datastore put at the end of the request. This is the highest latency option, but only slightly - datastore puts are fairly fast. This solution also consumes the least resources of all the options.
2. Accumulate logs and enqueue a task queue task with them, which writes them to the datastore (or does whatever else you want with them). This is slightly faster (task queue enqueues tend to be quick), but it's slightly more complicated, and limited to 100kb of data (which hopefully shouldn't be a limitation).
3. Enqueue a pull task with the data, and have a regular push task or a backend consume the queue and batch-and-insert into the datastore. This is more complicated than option 2, but also more efficient.
4. Run a backend that accumulates and writes logs, and make URLFetch calls to it to store logs. The urlfetch handler can write the data to the backend's memory and return asynchronously, making this the fastest in terms of added user latency (less than 1ms for a urlfetch call)! This will require waiting for Python 2.7, though, since you'll need multi-threading to process the log entries asynchronously.

You might also want to take a look at the Prospective Search API, which may allow you to do some filtering and pre-processing on the log data.

Comment: I already played with your ideas 2 and 3. I guess I'll do something like that. tks

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping a memcache data structure of request info (recorded as they arrive) and then run an every 5 minute (or faster) cron job that crunches the stats on the last 5 minutes of requests from the memcache and just records those stats in the data store for that 5 minute interval. The same (or a different) cron job could then clear the memcache too - so that it doesn't get too big.

Then you can run big-picture analysis based on the aggregate of 5 minute interval stats, which might be more manageable than analyzing hours of 1500req/s data.

Comment: that was a thought. We even don't have to worry about growing memcaches as they get deleted automatically. But that same feature is a risk, since I have no guarantee that in the next seconds there will still be data in the memcache. And as we're talking billings, there's no room for even the smallest mistake!

Comment: If the data is worth _real money_ to you, then pay the CPU/datastore costs and store it - no doubt. If it's just crunching stats data and losing 1-2 minutes of it wouldn't be the end of the world, then memcache would probably be fine. But if the data is not worth > CPU+Datastore costs... then I don't know what you should do :P

Comment: the problem is not the costs. The problem is how to implement it so that it is both fast and reliable.